# Rapidly Display Images With Tkinter

Tags: python, image, performance, tkinter, cpu-usage

I am looking for an efficient way to **rapidly** display images with tkinter, and I mean like really fast. Currently I have this code:

```
from tkinter import*
import threading
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("testing")


def img1():
    threading.Timer(0.2, img1).start()
    whitei = PhotoImage(file="white.gif")
    white = Label(root, image=whitei)
    white.image = whitei
    white.place(x=0, y=0)

def img2():
    threading.Timer(0.2, img2).start()
    blacki = PhotoImage(file="black.gif")
    black = Label(root, image=blacki)
    black.image = blacki
    black.place(x=0, y=0)

img1()
time.sleep(0.1)
img2()

root.mainloop()
```

Essentially the code just displays a black and white image but it puts my CPU at 100% usage and is pretty slow no matter how small I make the amount of time each picture is displayed for. Is there a faster, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: 1st don't use `sleep()` in tkinter. This is a problem. Use `after()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, I would suggest using `after`. You aren't really supposed to alter any tkinter objects outside your main thread. Also, creating a new object each time isn't the most efficient. Here's something I would try:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("testing")

whitei = tk.PhotoImage(file="white_.gif")
blacki = tk.PhotoImage(file="black_.gif")

label = tk.Label(root, image=whitei)
label.image1 = whitei
label.image2 = blacki
label.place(x=0, y=0)

time_interval = 50

def img1():
    root.after(time_interval, img2)
    label.configure(image=whitei)

def img2():
    root.after(time_interval, img1)
    label.configure(image=blacki)

root.after(time_interval, img1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `root.after(time_interval, img1)` is more than needed for the first call. simply doing `img1()` is sufficient for the first call to `img1()`.

Comment: True. I couldn't decide, which way I wanted to go with it actually :)

Comment: My first example was going to be identical to yours. But I decided to use a slightly different approach. I create both labels and stack them. Then raise each one. What do you think is the better option here? Is it more efficient to update a label rapidly or more efficient to raise them?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, works great! I appreciate how compact it is.

Comment: @Mihkel No problem!

Comment: @Mike-SMT I actually like your approach too. It might be faster to raise but not sure. Also probably depends on the exact use.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use threading. 2nd unless you are using `sleep()` inside of a separate thread you should never use sleep in a tkinter application. `sleep()` interrupts the mainloop and will cause tkinter to freeze up until sleep is finished. This is 99.9% of the time not what you want to do so here you should use `after()` for any timed events.

You can simple create each label for each image and then with a tracking variable raise the correct label to the top.

Here is a simple example.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("testing")
current_image = ""

black_image = PhotoImage(file="black.gif")
white_image = PhotoImage(file="white.gif")
black_label = Label(root, image=black_image)
white_label = Label(root, image=white_image)
black_label.image = black_image
white_label.image = white_image
black_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
white_label.grid(row=0, column=0)


def loop_images():
    global current_image, black_image, white_image
    if current_image == "white":
        black_label.tkraise(white_label)
        current_image = "black"
    else:
        white_label.tkraise(black_label)
        current_image = "white"
    root.after(100, loop_images)

loop_images()
root.mainloop()
```